# how to zoom in or out components in fram (python , pyqt6)?

Tags: python, geometry, zooming, pyqt6

hi guys I'm try to make desktop application for my work
general idea draw schematic to circuit board
i made some buttons as components ( capacitor - resistor ) and i need to zoom in and out all components
rules
save distance between them and save the relationship between width and height

```
def zoom_out(self,button: QPushButton):
    top = button.geometry().getRect()[0]
    left = button.geometry().getRect()[1]
    width = button.geometry().getRect()[2]
    hieght = button.geometry().getRect()[3]
    button.setGeometry( 1 + (top + 0.4) ,left + (left + 0.4),width + 4, hieght + 2)
```

something like that

any ideas or is their anther method make it right ?

Comment: For such applications, using widgets is normally discouraged, as that's not their intended purpose. You should look into the [graphics view framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/graphicsview.html) instead, which natively includes support for transformations like "zoom" (scaling).